# How to get row count for large dataset in Informatica?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to get the row count for a dataset with 280 fields with out having affect on the performance. Looking for best possible  ways to perform.

Answer (score 0):

The better option to avoid performance issue is, use sorter transformation and sort the columns and pass the pipeline to aggregator transformation. In aggregator transformation please check the option sorted input.

In terms if your source is a database then, index the required conditional columns in the table and also partition the table if required.

Comment: Hey Jim, the issue was with aggregator I need to eliminate  agg and implement same in using expression  as it doesn't  take cache.

Comment: Adding Sorter just to use sorted input on Aggregator is not a good option. It decreases performance and just moves the heavy part over to Sorter

Comment: You can not group the data if you eliminate aggregator transformation. That cannot be achieved in expression transformation. Or try aggregating data in source query itself. It its a flat file, you have no option, you should go through aggregator transformation. If you are still not ok, final option is partition the pipeline in the wotkflow

Answer (score 0):

For your solution, I have in mind 2 options:

1. Using Aggregator (remember to use a predefined order by to improve performance with the next trans), SQ > Aggregator > Target. Inside the aggregator add new ports with the sum() and/or count() functions. Remember to select the columns to group

   Check this out this example:
   https://www.guru99.com/aggregator-transformation-informatica.html
2. Using Source Qualifier query override. Use a traditional select count/sum with group by from the database- SQ > Target.

By the way. Informatica is very good with the performance, more than the columns you need to review how many records you are processing. A best practice is always to stress the datasource/database more than the Infa app.

Regards,

- Juan

Answer (score -1):

If all you need is just to count the rows, use the Aggregator. That's what it's for. However, this will create cache - to limit it's size, use a single port.

To avoid caching, you can use a variable in expression and just increment it. This however will give you an extra column with all rows numbered, not just a single value. You'll still need to aggregate it. Here it would be possible to use aggregater with no function to return just the last value.